# Python: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror, iterable, namedtuple

I tried to do calculation in python using values accessed for any pair of two rows when iterating through a tuple list but I received the type error as below. Does anyone have idea how to solve this? Thanks!

The code is shown below:

```
for ws1 in ccy_results:
            for ws2 in ccy_results:
                variance = ws1.WS * ws2.WS
                K += variance
```

Error message:

```
    K += variance
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

An extract of ccy_results is shown below:

```
[ws(Qualifier='AUD', Curve='Libor3m', Tenor='1m', WS=214000000.0), 
ws(Qualifier='AUD', Curve='Libor3m', Tenor='2y', WS=-106000000.0), 
ws(Qualifier='AUD', Curve='Libor3m', Tenor='6m', WS=213000000.0),
ws(Qualifier='CHF', Curve='Libor6m', Tenor='15y', WS=-200000000.0), 
ws(Qualifier='CHF', Curve='Libor6m', Tenor='20y', WS=540000000.0),
ws(Qualifier='CHF', Curve='Libor6m', Tenor='30y', WS=756000000.0)]
```

I tried to do checking by printing ws1.WS using the below code but all WS in ccy_results appear. I think this is the reason. How can I solve this issue?

```
for ws1 in ccy_results:
            for ws2 in ccy_results:
                print(ws1.WS)
```

---

```
import collections
ws = collections.namedtuple('ws',('Qualifier', 'Curve', 'Tenor', 'WS'))
ccy_results = [ws(Qualifier='AUD', Curve='Libor3m', Tenor='1m', WS=214000000.0), 
ws(Qualifier='AUD', Curve='Libor3m', Tenor='2y', WS=-106000000.0), 
ws(Qualifier='AUD', Curve='Libor3m', Tenor='6m', WS=213000000.0),
ws(Qualifier='CHF', Curve='Libor6m', Tenor='15y', WS=-200000000.0), 
ws(Qualifier='CHF', Curve='Libor6m', Tenor='20y', WS=540000000.0),
ws(Qualifier='CHF', Curve='Libor6m', Tenor='30y', WS=756000000.0)]
K = []
for ws1 in ccy_results:
    for ws2 in ccy_results:
        variance = ws1.WS * ws2.WS
        K += variance
```

Comment: what's your desired output...you are looping twice and doing??

Comment: Are those namedtuples and is `ccy_results` the list in your question? What is `K`? We should be able to copy and paste directly from your [mre] and be able to reproduce the problem.  We should have to guess what things are or how they were *made* - that could be important to solving the problem.

Comment: @Ajay I want to get the product of WSs for any pair of 2 rows when iterating through the namedtuples ccy_results

Comment: @wwii Yes, ```ccy_results``` are namedtuples. I would like to iterate through ccy_results in this function. ```K ``` is empty list that ```K=[]``` and to store the result obtained through iterating namedtuples ```ccy_results```

Comment: I edited your question - if that edit is not an accurate [mre] please [edit] it.

Comment: @wwii Thanks a lot for editing! Is there any way that I can access the `WS` of single row when I iterate through the namedtuples `ccy_results`? I am trying to do so using `ws1.WS` and `ws2.WS` but they are calling the full list of the namedtuples, which is not what I want.

Comment: @user15253500 - You specified `for any pair of two rows` - your nested loops give you the *cartesian product* of the list with itself maybe you are looking for combinations instead? It isn't really clear what you are trying to accomplish.  You should probably ask a new question. Maybe you can make use of one of the combinatoric iterators in the [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The augmented assignment operation, `+=`, for a list is *equivalent to* `list.extend` which expects an iterable for its argument ( the left-hand-side of the expression ).

Change

```
K += variance
```

to

```
K.append(variance)
```

---

From [Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

| Operation | Result |
| --- | --- |
| s.extend(t) or s += t | extends s with the contents of t (for the most part the same as s[len(s):len(s)] = t) |