# How to add 100 words to a list using while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

i want to add a word for ex. 100 times to a list, here is my code

my expected result is ['word', 'word', 'word'...]

```
i = 1

text = [ ]

while i <= 100:

  text += 'word'

  i += 1


print(text)
```

the output is -> 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 'w', ...

all the letters are added separately,

Can smbdy explain why? And what is the right code for adding 100 words to a list ?

Thank you

Comment: try `text += ["word"]` or `text.append("word")`, or just `text = ["word"] * 100`

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of what `+=` does to a string and a list

Comment: [`+=` operation for a list is equivalent to `.extend`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66304392/2823755) - it *adds* each item in the right-hand-side to the list. Strings are iterable and the operation sees each character as an item.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `text.append(word)` or `text += ['word']` instead. When adding items to a list, `+=` is effectively the same as `.extend`.

Since strings can be iterated on, it's adding each character into the list individually

Answer (score 0):

Use extend.

```
text = ['existing', 'words']
text.extend(['word']*100)

print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mul=100
text = ['existing', 'words']
# repeat the text n-times
m_text=[[x]*mul for x in text]
# flattened list
flat_list = [item for sublist in m_text for item in sublist]
```